# Installing multiple windows on same PC a good idea for security?

Tags: security, multi-boot

Is installing multiple windows on the same PC (NOT virtual machines, but dual-boot) a good idea in terms of security?

Security in terms of tinkering with OS level stuff, or visiting "dodgy" websites in one boot, but doing all normal stuff (like banking) on the other?

As far as I understand, this should be the same as how researchers have a virtual environment when doing pen-testing, or running a virtual environment to setup a "honeypot"; there should be no way for viruses to leak to the other version?

How would this strategy compare to using a VM to run "unsafe stuff" instead? A motivation to using parallel installs instead of VM would be running pirated games for example (you never know if the cracked version is stealing something in the background).

Comment: This only makes sens in case the "normal stuff installation" is protected e.g. by Bitlocker encryption or on a drive that is disconnected (no power and/or SATA cable) whil the other OS is running.

Comment: And this is not needed if the "unsafe version" is running on a VM instead? So this is one advantage of running a VM for unsafe stuff?

Comment: VM sounds better, but it is not as secure as e.g. a Bitlocker protected parallel installation as VM software some times has vulnerabilities that allows to execute code on the host from within the VM. BTW: in IT you speak of security, not safety. PC safety would something like avoiding that your PC-tower tilt over and lands on your feet, hurting you.

Comment: Good point, edited

Answer (score 0):

This is typically already done when you install Windows, technically.

You have the main Windows OS that you normally use on a big partition, and a small alternate Windows OS on a recovery partition, providing a recovery environment.  This is why when you install Windows it creates a 100MB partition, to store the recovery environment OS.

Here's the thing - if you have a first operating system on a hard drive, and that hard drive has multiple operating systems, your first operating system can still access the entire hard drive.  So viruses or malware can still mess with things in other partitions.  It will protect you from irreversible actions done by tinkering, though--and in that case, it's justified.

However, on modern hardware, especially with NVME drives, Windows installs rather quickly, and other programs can be installed very quickly as well.  Check your reinstall time - it could be less than 5 minutes.  So, unless you have many and/or large programs to install up and over Windows, it's probably just easier to wipe and reinstall.

Comment: How would this strategy compare to using a VM to run "unsafe stuff" instead? A motivation to using parallel installs instead of VM would be running pirated games for example (you never know if the cracked version is stealing something in the background).

Comment: A VM isolates the virtual OS from the host OS's disk better--the virtual OS is only going to see the virtual disk, no more, no less.  This is not to say that some very advanced malware can't break through the VM but you're definitely putting more barriers in front of it.  Encryption as @TheKrafter2217 will definitely protect the other partition from accessing data, but some nasty malware (or yourself accidentally) can still do something like overwrite the encrypted partition with random data or delete partitions.

Comment: That's getting into fairly high levels of paranoia, though, and probably not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having a dual-boot; one for sketchy stuff, and one for "safe" things is a neat idea. Just be sure to encrypt the "safe" install because the "unsafe" install will still be able to read the other drive unless it's encrypted.
Though it might not be as practical as a VM, it should be fine if you're willing to reboot and enter BIOS to change your boot drive whenever you want to change activities.

--Krafter